# how to pass data in body using csv by jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ge0z.png)1.record script using blazemetre plugin 2.run script using j meter, it is running 3.pass the value using csv 4.For that i configure csv 5.I pass the variable name in csv 6.CSV path also define in csv configue 7.Jmeter not read value from csv[pass variable value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HcX8.png)

[csv data set configue[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfuZS.png)

Comment: edit your question with full error and CSV definitions

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the CSV data set config

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're getting [Filename must not be null or empty](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.java#L256) error, please make sure to specify the name (if the file is in "bin" folder of JMeter) or full path to your CSV file in the Filename section of the CSV Data Set Config

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set]

More information on parameterizing your JMeter test using external data sources: [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri T guess is right. You are facing the same issue.

From your screenshots, it seems you are using two csv's data set config. One is having full path and other is blank. Remove the one which is blank i.e.abc